# Render jade template with parameters that are angular binded upon render

Tags: angularjs, express, pug

Upon request I render a jade template passing some parameters to template

```
res.render("result.jade",{order_id: "abc123"});
```

What is the best way to bind this passed parameters to scope variables when being rendered on client side? I haven't found any good solution except to render it to some hidden dom element and then take its text value (with jquery, for example) and assign it to scope variable, like this

```
// jade template
div.hidden #{order_id}


// javascript code
$scope.order_id = $(".hidden").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you make this data available as a separate API call, such as REST.  Then your Angular app would call this API to get the data on load, etc.

Comment: the solution that I currently use seems to be better. And querying for the same data just to bind it looks illogical, if it is already present on client side after rendered template is sent to client side.